# How to count the number of child nodes in a directed acyclic graph with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have simplified an xml file that represents a directed acyclic graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
  <item id="1">
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <parent idref="1" />
  </item>
  <item id="3">
    <parent idref="1" />
  </item>
  <item id="4">
    <parent idref="3" />
  </item>
  <item id="5">
    <parent idref="4" />
  </item>
  <item id="6">
    <parent idref="3" />
  </item>
  <item id="7">
    <parent idref="4" />
  </item>
  <item id="8">
    <parent idref="4" />
  </item>
  <item id="9">
    <parent idref="4" />
  </item>
  <item id="10">
    <parent idref="6" />
  </item>
</items>
```

This representation allows for infinite depth (I don't know the mathematical term).  Every item has one and only one parent, except for the root item, which has no parent.  Each item can have 0 to any number of child items.  Every item is identified by its id, which is an arbitrary label.

It might be easier to visualize the graph in dot notation. In my file, it's easier to see that item 3 has two children nodes, and item 4 has 4:

```
digraph
{
    1 -> {2, 3}
    3 -> {4, 6}
    4 -> {5, 7, 8, 9}
    6 -> 10
}
```

Counting the number of children for item 3 is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(items/item/parent[@idref='3'])" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xslt stylesheet outputs 2, which is correct.  If I change the 3 to a 4, then the output is 4, which is also correct.

**Question**: I want to count all the children items of a specific item.

For item 3, the correct answer is 7 (items 4,6,5,7,8,9,10).  For item 1, the answer is 9.  For item 7, it's 0.  I suspect the answer involves recursion, which I've successfully used to construct parts of the tree, but not to pass values around or computes sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For following cross-references I would suggest to set up keys and then indeed, to solve the problem, recursion is (the other) key to the solution, so in XSLT 2 or 3 you can do that with a recursive function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="start-id">7</xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="child" match="item" use="parent/@idref"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:descendants" as="element(item)*">
      <xsl:param name="item" as="element(item)*"/>
      <xsl:sequence 
        select="let $children := key('child', $item/@id, root($item))
                return ($children | $children!mf:descendants(.))"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(mf:descendants(key('id', $start-id)))"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpH/0 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpH/1 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpH/2 are some examples.

For XSLT 2 you would use a local `xsl:variable` instead of the `let $children` used above:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

  <xsl:param name="start-id">1</xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="child" match="item" use="parent/@idref"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:descendants" as="element(item)*">
      <xsl:param name="item" as="element(item)*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('child', $item/@id, root($item))"/>
      <xsl:sequence 
        select="$children | $children/mf:descendants(.)"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(mf:descendants(key('id', $start-id)))"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/pPgCcou

For XSLT 1 you could use a slightly different approach with a recursive, named template that collects the descendants until it finds no more children and then outputs the count:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="start-id">7</xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="child" match="item" use="parent/@idref"/>

    <xsl:template name="count-descendants">
        <xsl:param name="descendants" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="level"/>
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('child', $level/@id)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($children)">
                <xsl:value-of select="count($descendants)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="count-descendants">
                    <xsl:with-param name="descendants" select="$descendants | $children"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$children"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="start-item" select="key('id', $start-id)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="count-descendants">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$start-item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsK/0 and 
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsK/1 and
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsK/2 have the sample data.

Comment: Since I want to incorporate this solution into PHP, XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 are out of scope.  But the 1.0 version seems to work!

Comment: I've incorporated the xslt 1.0 solution into my PHP code and works really fast.  The DAG I have has just over 300 nodes about 40 deep.  I thought it would be really slow, but it isn't.  This is a great solution and with a little more ruminating I'll understand it.  Thanks, Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, here's another approach:

```
<xsl:param name="start-id">7</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="id" match="item" use="@id"/>

<xsl:function name="f:has-ancestor" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="d" as="item"/>
  <xsl:param name="a" as="item"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="exists($d) and ($a is $d or 
       f:has-ancestor(key('id', $d/parent/@idref), $a))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

then

```
select="count(//item[f:has-ancestor(., key('id', $start-id))])"/>
```

(Which of them is faster depends, of course, on the bushiness of your tree.)

Comment: I can't use this solution since it involves XSLT 2.0 and PHP doesn't use it.  But to get a response from The Michael Kay means I have been touched by XML greatness.  Your book XSLT 2nd edition is an invaluable reference to me.

Comment: Saxon/C offers the ability to invoke XSLT 3.0 from PHP.